# how to change the time zone configuration of my windows 2003 server from GMT to UTC

Tags: c#, time, timezone, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

how to change time zone configuration of my windows 2003 server from GMT to UTC?

right now the problem is DataSet serialization (DateTime columns) between windows 2003 server and windows 2008 server via .NET Remoting. (.NET Framework 4)
they both on the same time zone (also same LAN).
the 2008 server timezone setting use UTC.
the 2003 server timezone setting use GMT.

if i change just for testing only the 2003 server to another 2008 server which use UTC setting, everything work well (there is no problem between 2 2008 servers).

so i think the problem is because one server is GMT and the another is UTC,
or may be the 2003 server need time zone hotfix (although the problematics dates are in the past, year 1975 for example).

Comment: I don't understand - AFAIK UTC is the same as GMT with no daylight saving... so what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: @Yahia by definition, GMT isn't subject to daylight saving.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you ask the question, gtm and utc are the same

Comment: is your real problem that one server adjusts for dst and not the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GMT and UTC are the same thing. All these are the same:

> Greenwich Time / Zulu Time / UTC

See: http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/

Comment: Well, give or take anything under 1 second difference, they are the same ;p

Comment: Still, I think the problem is not GMT<->UTC but rather an incompatibility between 2003 and 2008. To further explore the issue, please try to set both servers (2003 and 2008) to a totally different time zone, which is identical at both of them, say one country with a known time that has not daylight savings time etc. and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: Ofer, i try your advice and it's work well with time zone with no daylight saving. so what is the problem, both servers use Israel time zone(Jerusalem) with DST. thanks.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917534/why-is-this-giving-me-2-different-sets-of-timezones/2917554#2917554, and read all comments after the answer. I think it will answer your case. Anyway that's the best I can get...